# Running Windows .exe file with multiple arguments using Java ProcessBuilder is not producing any output file as expected

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I am trying to run an external .exe program in Windows 7 from my Java code using ProcessBuilder

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\hMetis\\1.5.3-win32\\hmetis.exe", "test.hgr", "2", "1", "10", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0");
Process process = pb.start();
```

However, when I run this standalone .exe from Windows using cmd it outputs the results in the command prompt as well as producing a file containing the results. I am not seeing any of these two happening while running the .exe from Java

Any kind suggestions what I am missing out?

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and (continue to) build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What are you doing after `pb.start()` in your program?

Comment: @Ingo .. absolutely nothing after pb.start(); just end of the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use this to set working directory :

```
File f = new File("C:\\hMetis\\1.5.3-win32");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c","start","hmetis.exe", "test.hgr", "2", "1", "10", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0");
pb.directory(f);
Process process = pb.start();
```

Comment: Running the suggested code produces the following error:

    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hmetis.exe" (in directory "C:\hMetis\1.5.3-win32"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Sorry, i add "cmd", "/c","start", to the arguments , it should work now.

Comment: it worked !!! Thanks a lot for giving a absolute correct answer. I am now getting the expected results as well as the output files.