# Using Java ProcessBuilder to run native Windows .exe producing error :: The directory name is invalid

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have the following Java code to run a native Windows .exe file using ProcessBuilder

```
public class HMetis {
    private String exec_name = null;    
    private String[] hmetis_args = {"hmetis.exe", "null", "2", "1", "10", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0"};

    private Path path;
    private File file;

    public HMetis(String hgraph_exec, String hgraph_file) {
        this.exec_name = hgraph_exec;       
        this.hmetis_args[1] = hgraph_file;
    }       

    public void runHMetis() throws IOException {    
        this.path = Paths.get("C:\\hMetis\\1.5.3-win32");
        this.file = new File(path+"\\"+this.exec_name+".exe");      

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(this.hmetis_args);
        pb.directory(this.file);

        try {       
            Process process = pb.start();                       
        } finally {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

after running this code I am getting the below error although from the message it seems the directory name is fully formed and OK !! Any suggestions please?

```
Cannot run program "hmetis.exe" (in directory "C:\hMetis\1.5.3-win32\hmetis.exe"):CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
```

Comment: It seems that you are appending the executable name to the directory path - did you try without that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Windows .exe file with multiple arguments using Java ProcessBuilder is not producing any output file as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809295/running-windows-exe-file-with-multiple-arguments-using-java-processbuilder-is-n)  Edit your earlier question, rather than start new ones about the same problem.  You also seem to have ignored the 1sat point of my advice to you there.  So why should this duplicate question be any different?

Comment: @Andrew not duplicate these are two different cases with different observations. Previously asked question says that the probably the .exe file is running without producing any error message but the .exe file was not working as it is expected to be.

Comment: I will not be going to make any argument with you as you completely misunderstood the intention and I don't care whether anyone say it is a rubbish code or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the complete path to the executable file as the ProcessBuilder's working directory:

```
this.file = new File(path+"\\"+this.exec_name+".exe");      
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(this.hmetis_args);
pb.directory(this.file);
                    ^
                    |
                    ++++++++ "C:\hMetis\1.5.3-win32\hmetis.exe"
                             should be "C:\hMetis\1.5.3-win32"
```

However, you want to set the working **directory** only, like

```
pb.directory(this.path.toFile());
```

---

In addition, it seems that `ProcessBuilder.directory()` does not set the "working directory" as one might expect - at least not to find the executable. A similar issue is described at [ProcessBuilder can't find file?!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847242/processbuilder-cant-find-file). At least on Windows, executables in the current working directory are usually found first (Unix is a different thing).

An easy fix would be to add the absolute path name to the command array, like

```
String[] hmetis_args = {"C:\\hMetis\\1.5.3-win32\\hmetis.exe", "null", "2", "1", "10", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0"};
```

---

See also

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: pb.directory() is expecting a File object therefore setting pb.directory(this.path) is producing error

Comment: You can convert the `Path` object to `File` - see my updated answer. Probably an easier solution would be to use a `File` object directly - a `File` object can also represent a directory

Comment: after coverting the path.toFile() I am getting the following error:

    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hmetis.exe" (in directory "C:\hMetis\1.5.3-win32"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: regarding the updated answer: I did as you said by only using this.path omitting using this.file

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? When I unzip http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/fetch/sw/hmetis/hmetis-1.5.3-WIN32.zip, it shows **hmetis-1.5.3-WIN32** (as one directory name, not a separate `hmetis` directory)

Comment: I created the dir by myself and copy the executables from the original .zip file

Comment: See my updated answer - obviously `ProcessBuilder.directory()` behaves somewhat different from what I would expect from the docs ...

Comment: I followed your suggestions and use the absolute dir location as you said. Now Although I am not getting any error messages in Eclipse console but from stdout I am receiving the following message: ERROR> Can't open input file: No such file or directory

I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-capturing-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-to-another-stre to capture the stdout messages

Thanks again Andreas for pointing me some links. I am now going through http://www.coderanch.com/t/517098/java/java/Working-ProcessBuilder-working-directory

Comment: The updated solution provided by Gladiator at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809295/running-windows-exe-file-with-multiple-arguments-using-java-processbuilder-is-n?lq=1 worked for me. 
Many thanks once again for providing appropriate and correct suggestions. I will explore through this particular issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace
`pb.directory(this.file);`
with
`pb.directory(this.file.getParentFile());` ?

Comment: pb.directory() is expecting a File object therefore setting pb.directory(this.path) is producing error

Comment: doing as you suggested producing the below error:

The method directory(File) in the type ProcessBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (String)